# Access the XML attributes of a SimpleXML node

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have a XML file as following:

```
<menus>
    <defaultMenu>
        <group>
            <menuItem name="Example one" url="http://www.google.com">
                <menuItem name="Example Two" url="http://www.yahoo.com" />
                <menuItem name="Example Three" url="http://www.bing.com" />
            </menuItem>
        </group>
    </defaultMenu>
</menus>
```

I want to loop over the `<menuItem>` tags to gather all URLs, but didn't found how to access the attributes of a SimpleXML node.

Here is the code I tried without success :

```
$contentXML = simplexml_load_file('file.xml');
$urls = array();

foreach($xml->menus->defaultMenu->group->menuItem as $menuItem) {
    $urls[] = $menuItem->url;
}
```

However, this method is not the right, as the array only get empty values after the loop. So, how do I access the XML attributes of a SimpleXML node ?

Answer (score 0):

To access the attributes of a SimpleXML node, you have to use the node object as an array. Example:

```
foreach($contentXML->menus->defaultMenu->group->menuItem as $menuItem) {
    $urls[] = $menuItem["url"];
}
```

See the [basic usage](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php) page of the PHP documentation.

You can also use the `attributes()` method on the node, but that's quite verbose.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `children()` and `attributes()` methods:

```
foreach($contentXML->menus->defaultMenu->group->menuItem->children() as $menuItem) {

    $urls[] = $menuItem->attributes()['url']; // (PHP v >= 5.4)

    $attrs = $menuItem->attributes(); // (PHP v < 5.4)
    $urls[] = $attrs['url']; 

}
```

[Doc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php)

Answer (score 0):

Use `xpath` to select all `url`-attributes in a simple way *without iterating* over the XML.
`xpath` is like SQL for XML:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($x); // assume XML in $x

$urls = $xml->xpath("//*[@url]/@url");
```

You are done. See it working: https://eval.in/159586

Comments:

The `xpath`-expression reads as:

- `//*` wherever in the hierarchy, select whatever node...
- `[@url]` that has the attribute `url`...
- `/@url` and return the attribute `url` only.

`$urls` is an array of `SimpleXml`-Objects, cast to `string`if necessary, e.g. when making comparisons.